# How Do I Append These Two Divs Together?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".content").hide();
//toggle the componenet with class msg_body
jQuery(".heading").click(function()
{
jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(200);
});
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="layer1">

<p class="heading">Into to paragraph</p>

<div class="content">The remainder of paragraph</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.layer1 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.heading {
color: #bfbfbf;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
}
.content {
padding: 0px;
color: #bfbfbf;
margin: 0px;
}
```

I want the remainder of the paragraph to continue on the same line. I tried inline, removing the p tag, etc.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm being a grammar nazi, but you don't append two things together.  You append one (or more) items to another item.  I only bring it up because it might assist you in searching for answers on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `heading` and `content` to `span` tags.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8pa3n/

Comment: Thank you Matt! That did the job.

Comment: If this helped, please mark this as the answer.  Also, you've got a few older questions that you haven't accepted as answers.  Please do so!

Comment: If it's smacking me in the face, I don't see where to mark as answered.

Comment: Under the up/down arrows, there should be a (grey?) check mark.  Click that check!

Comment: Before I start a new post. Do you know how to improve the .slideToggle in the above example? It's very jerking and the text moves around trying to justify. I would like a nice fade in and fade out without the text jumping around. Thanks!

Comment: No, sorry.  I've never experienced that.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Set `.heading` and `.content` to `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` and that should do what you want.

Comment: This is mostly a preference thing, but I hate seeing block elements redefined as inline (and vice versa).  If you're doing that, you should probably choose a more appropriate HTML tag.

Comment: I could see it both ways. "Don't try to be something you're not" but at the same time, you might still want them to be semantically represented by a `<p>` or `<h1>` and you want them displayed a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

```
.heading{
width:50%;
float:left;
}
.content{
width:50%;
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give the content class

```
display: inline
```

to give it the appearance of being on the same line.

OR

More appropriately maybe is using two span tags.

```
<span>paragraph 1</span>
<span>paragraph 2</span>
```

Comment: This is mostly a preference thing, but I hate seeing block elements redefined as inline (and vice versa).  If you're doing that, you should probably choose a more appropriate HTML tag.

Comment: I agree so I changed my answer around a bit.

Comment: I'm upvoting your answer since you got there first.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left`

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W7VgK/1/)**

```
.heading {
color: #bfbfbf;
cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
float: left;
}

.content {
float: left;
position: relative;
padding: 0px;
color: #bfbfbf;
margin: 0px;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be better for you to append the next paragraph text within "heading". By adding different elements side by side, it may not turn out nicely on some browsers and if your next paragraph(s) after "heading" is too long, it could cause lines differences in other elements.